# mvn archtype:generate command does not work on D: or d: in windows

Tags: windows, maven, maven-3, windows-10

mvn archtype:generate command works fine if I call it from C:
however, whenever I tried invoking it from d: it's not functional.

Here is trace I got from command line

```
D:\>mvn archtype:generate

D:\>if "C:\Users\Anand Chavan" == "" (set "HOME=C:\Users\Anand Chavan" )

D:\>if not "" == "" goto skipRcPre

D:\>if exist "C:\Users\Anand Chavan\mavenrc_pre.bat" call "C:\Users\Anand Chavan\mavenrc_pre.bat"

D:\>if exist "C:\Users\Anand Chavan\mavenrc_pre.cmd" call "C:\Users\Anand Chavan\mavenrc_pre.cmd"

D:\>set ERROR_CODE=0

D:\>if not "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79" == "" goto OkJHome

D:\>if exist "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" goto chkMHome

D:\>if not "D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3" == "" goto valMHome

D:\>if not "_3" == "_\" goto checkMCmd

D:\>if exist "D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin\mvn.cmd" goto init

D:\>set MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=archtype:generate

D:\>set MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=

D:\>IF NOT "" == "" goto endDetectBaseDir

D:\>set EXEC_DIR=D:\

D:\>set WDIR=D:\

D:\>IF EXIST "D:\"\.mvn goto baseDirFound

D:\>cd ..

D:\>IF "D:\" == "D:\" goto baseDirNotFound

D:\>set MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=D:\

D:\>cd "D:\"

D:\>IF NOT EXIST "D:\\.mvn\jvm.config" goto endReadAdditionalConfig

D:\>SET MAVEN_JAVA_EXE="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe"

D:\>for %i in ("D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3"\boot\plexus-classworlds-*) do set CLASSWORLDS_JAR="%i"

D:\>set CLASSWORLDS_JAR="D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar"

D:\>set CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

D:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe"    -classpath "D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" "-Dclassworlds.conf=D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher archtype:generate
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

D:\>if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error

D:\>set ERROR_CODE=1

D:\>if not "" == "" goto skipRcPost

D:\>if exist "C:\Users\Anand Chavan\mavenrc_post.bat" call "C:\Users\Anand Chavan\mavenrc_post.bat"

D:\>if exist "C:\Users\Anand Chavan\mavenrc_post.cmd" call "C:\Users\Anand Chavan\mavenrc_post.cmd"

D:\>if "" == "on" pause

D:\>if "" == "on" exit 1

D:\>exit /B 1

D:\>
```

Can I please get expert advice on the same?

Here is list of environment variables I have already added -

```
JAVA_HOME                C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

JRE_HOME                 C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

M2_HOME                  D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3

M2                       D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin

MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO         ON

MAVEN_HOME               D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3

Path                     D:\LIBRARIES\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next release of Maven 3.3.x, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5796. I've already tested it with a RC and can confirm that it works. We've already tried to push a new release but discovered some regressions. These have been fixed, so you can expect a new release soon.